# Django crispy forms get call with search

Tags: django, get

I am trying to use django crispy forms to do a filter and search for items in a my database. All or most of the examples I found are related to "post" while a "get" call is necessary for a search. While I can get "country" to work by having the user select it from the modelform itself, I am having issues adding search ranges such as salary and a detailed search.

Is there a way to add search functions that work together with the form inputs that are not part of the what is inside the database? For instance, the Div(AppendedText('salaryrange', '$') and Div(AppendedText('Test', 'Search') below is requiring me to insert a field into 'salaryrange' and 'test' but these are items that may or may not exist in the database.

I have gone thought the documents but they give examples that require the field input, all the items I found online are related to posting. I think if crispy form method allows a "get" there should be a way to do this.

Below is my sample code

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = [
                "country",
                "salary",
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'get'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', value='Submit', css_class='btn-success'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            TabHolder(
                Tab('Country',
                    Div('country', css_class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'),
                ),
                Tab('Salary',
                    Div(AppendedText('salaryrange', '$'), css_class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'),
                    Div(AppendedText('salaryrange', '$'), css_class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'),
                ),
                Tab('Detailed Search',
                    Div(AppendedText('Test', 'Search'), css_class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'),
                ),
            ),
        )
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want an extra form field that is not related to you're database?

Comment: It looks like this isn't really a question about crispy forms, it's a question about Django forms generally. Django crispy forms simply helps you to style a form, it doesn't change anything about the core functionality of Django forms. You can add a non-model field to a model form just as you add fields to a normal Django `Form`.

Comment: Hey both thanks for the reply. ChidG - My mind was stuck in the box which I need to use the functionality of crispy forms to get it to work, that's why I was searching everywhere within the crispy documentation and it did not help. I just added a non model field and it works now. I will post the solution in a minute and close this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add non model fields to modelforms. Just added three non-model fields to the form to get what is required. Forms displayed with a combination of both model and non model fields.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    search = forms.CharField(label='Search', max_length=100)
    salarymaxrange = forms.IntegerField()
    salaryminrange = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Worker
        fields = [
                "country",
                "salary",
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'get'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', value='Submit', css_class='btn-success'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            TabHolder(
                Tab('Country',
                    Div('country', css_class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'),
                ),
                Tab('Salary',
                    Div(AppendedText('salarymaxrange', '$'), css_class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'),
                    Div(AppendedText('salaryminrange', '$'), css_class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'),
                ),
                Tab('Detailed Search',
                    Div(AppendedText('search', 'Search'), css_class='col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'),
                ),
            ),
        )
```